# COMO CONCATENAR VARIABLES CON '\' EN UN STORE PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un bulk insert a una tabla, pero no se como poner la dirección del archivo de entrada.

Este es el archivo o la dirección mencionada:

```
'\\192.198.225.19\DEVFiles\Boletines\'' + @filedir + ''\'' + @filepath + '''
```

Este es mi store procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER proc [dbo].[SP_Des ]

@filedir varchar(500) = null ,

@filepath varchar(500) =  null 

as 

Begin

Bulk insert [dbo].[V_Des ]
FROM '\\192.198.225.19\DEVFiles\Boletines\'' + @filedir + ''\'' + @filepath + '''

WITH 
( 
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR= '"|"',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

end
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes concatenar valores en el origen de un `BULK INSERT`. Necesitas generar código dinámico para lograrlo.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Des ]

@filedir varchar(500) = null ,

@filepath varchar(500) =  null 

as 

Begin

DECLARE @BULKINSERT nvarchar(MAX);

SET @BULKINSERT = N'
Bulk insert [dbo].[V_Des ]
FROM ''\\192.198.225.19\DEVFiles\Boletines\' + @filedir + N'\' + @filepath + N'''

WITH 
( 
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR= ''"|"'',
        ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
)'

--PRINT @BULKINSERT;
EXEC sp_executesql @BULKINSERT;

end
GO
```

Comment: ¿Como genero un codigo dinámico?

Comment: Como se muestra en el ejemplo (aunque no se pinta correctamente el código)